# How to save user input in internal storage (android studio)

Tags: java, android, file, save

I'm not sure if it saves input  my code saves user input it doesn't load the file

I guess the write button works it shows the user input in the listView But I can't find the file name my anywhere

```
        btnwrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String msg = editText.getText().toString();
                if (addArray.contains(msg)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter Sth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try {
                    FileOutputStream Fops = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    Fops.write(msg.getBytes());
                    Fops.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    addArray.add(msg);
                    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String>(Activity_ToDoList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
                    show.setAdapter(adapter);
                    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("");

                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

Read button doesn't work at all and I can't see the problem

```
        btnread.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try{

                    InputStream inputreader = getAssets().open(filename);
                    BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputreader));


                    boolean hasNextLine =true;
                    while (hasNextLine){
                        String line =  buffreader.readLine();
                        addArray.add(line);
                        hasNextLine = line != null;
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Activity_ToDoList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,addArray);

                    show.setAdapter(adapter);

                    inputreader.close();

                }
                catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e){

                }catch(java.io.IOException e){

                }

            }

        });
    }
```

}